# Microsoft Graph Api displays insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an admin account that am trying to update its data using microsoft Graph API via php Curl but its showing error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "110ac3f6-16d1-41a2-b2dc-add954514666",
            "date": "2017-12-04T00:12:02"
        }
    }
}
```

below is the code for updating

```
<?php 
session_start();

echo $acc= $_SESSION['access_token'];

$data_string = array("jobTitle" => 'Fibre ngineer', "officeLocation" => "SAMOLA"); 
$data = json_encode($data_string); 
//$data = $data_string; 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/@mydata.onmicrosoft.com", 
//CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", 
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PATCH", 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"accept: application/json", 
"authorization: Bearer $acc", 
"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
), 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);
$json = json_decode($response);

if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
//echo $response; 
}
?>
```

I have also set all the required permission like `Directory and Users read access` but cannot get it to work

Comment: You should probably add how you get the bearer token $acc.

Comment: Are you requesting `/users/@mydata.onmicrosoft.com`? That is a domain, not a user principal name.

Comment: At Marc, am using a user principal name, @mydata.onmicrosoft.com is just a camouflage because i dont want to expose my admin principal name to the public

Comment: Can you provide details on the bearer token please?  Which auth flow (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) did you use to acquire it?

Comment: At Dan, yes I used microsoft graph API authentication flow for PHP at this link **https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start**. I think the problem  has to do with JSON data sent over the API. A similar problem was posted and solved in the microsoft forum link below **https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/66a54e38-702c-4435-b59a-03abd5947513/while-trying-to-create-a-search-index-using-phpcurl-i-keep-getting-the-response-the-request-is?forum=azuresearch**